# Avoid features to be automatically selected in table

Tags: qgis-3, features, select-by-attribute

In the screenshot below you will notice that in *"Feature"*, a country has gotten automatically selected. I don't understand why. I have not selected any part of the data or the map. I don't want this because it is a cross country analysis.

In fact, in the dropdown box, not all the countries are appearing though I can see all these countries in the table.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

That is an example not a selection, when you start building your expression it will show you what the result is on that feature in the `Preview:` box. You can choose a different feature in the drop down box to see how the expression works for other features.

Comment: Hi Ian,That's the problem. Not all features are appearing in the drop down box.

Comment: Its a sample of the features, the cost of loading 1000s or 1000000s of features would be too much

Comment: Hi Ian, thank you so much. Just one more question. So suppose instead of Egypt (which appears in that features drop down box), I want to focus on another country in the data set like UK and that does not appear in the drop down box, how do I deal with that? Will this affect my results?

Comment: It is there to help you compose the query and has no effect on the outcome,

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: If this answered your question then you should click on the green accept checkmark next to it.